# Apex beginner - Email from a trigger

Tags: email, salesforce, apex-code, soql

This is the first bit of code I have written using APEX so am learning... know a bit of Java (to a graduate level) but I don't know why this is not working.

I know that it is not giving an error to salesforce as before it was telling me (hence the commented out debug at the end. I change a contacts email and it just does it, but I receive no emails! Here is the code and thank you for any help!

```
trigger Test1 on Contact (after update) {

//IF Email has changed (look at the old email and compare to new)
if(trigger.old[0].Email != trigger.new[0].Email){


    //Commit current transaction, reserver email capacity
    Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1);
    //Create an email message object
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

    //List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> results = new list<Messaging.SendEmailResult>();
    //hold email address
    String[] toAddresses = new String[] {trigger.new[0].Email};

    //Assign new address string
    mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
    //specify return ad (assuming as being sent from server)    
    mail.setReplyTo('XXX@example.com');
    //sender name
    mail.setSenderDisplayName('Mr Apex Tester');
    //Subject Specification
    mail.setSubject('Subjected to Learning');
    //And... the content
    mail.setPlainTextBody('You have just changed your SalesForce contact email from ' + trigger.old[0].Email + ' to ' + trigger.new[0].Email + '. If this was not intentional please log back into Salesforce.com and ammend you details.');

    //if (!results.get(0).isSuccess()){                      
        //System.debug('That didnt really work did it? Reason: ' + results.get(0).getErrors()[0].getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the first trouble into your code is that your trigger is not BULK
read about it here

[bulk trigger #1](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/04/20/writing-bulk-triggers-for-salesforce/)

[bulk trigger #2](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm)

the next trouble is that you don't send email with `Messaging.sendEmail`

try the following:

```apex
    trigger Test1 on Contact (after update) {
        Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(trigger.size);
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        for (Contact c : trigger.new) { // walk through all records which is processed
            Contact old = trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id); // get old record from oldMap
            if (old.Email != c.Email ) { // check current email 
                Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
                email.setToAddresses(new String[] {c.Email};);
                email.setReplyTo('XXX@example.com');
                email.setSenderDisplayName('Mr Apex Tester');
                email.setSubject('Subjected to Learning');
                email.setPlainTextBody('You have just changed your SalesForce contact email from ' + 
                    old.Email + ' to ' + c.Email +
                     '. If this was not intentional please log back into Salesforce.com and ammend you details.');
                emails.add(email);
            }
        }
        Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
    }
```

Comment: I will give it a go this morning thank you. This is the trouble, I have just graduated from uni and in my first industry related job. I am learning apex but thrown in at the deep end. I am amazed how little I have learnt from uni in respect to my career. I guess I have just spent 20k on widening my abilities to learn and doing so quicker. Sorry about the life story, thank you for the help.

Comment: @Phil you are welcome, it's normal that uni just teaches you how to learn and extremely broadens your mind and widens your horizons. In uni you have a possibility for experiments with wide range of technologies and you have incredible chance for choosing tech. which you're really wish. When you come in into industry from university, nobody expects that you're expert. Therefore don't stop with learning, because software developer's career is an infinite learning a something new. Good luck!